# How to fix Numpy 'otypes' within Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mlxtend

Objective: to run association rules on a binary values dataset

```
d = {'col1': [0, 0,1], 'col2': [1, 0,0], 'col3': [0,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This produces a data frame with 0's and 1's for corresponding column values.

The problem is when I make use of code like the following:

```
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules
frequent_itemsets = apriori(pattern_dataset, min_support=0.50,use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)
rules
```

Typically this runs just fine, but in running it this time I have encountered an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-46ec6f572255> in <module>()
      4 frequent_itemsets = apriori(pattern_dataset, min_support=0.50,use_colnames=True)
      5 frequent_itemsets
----> 6 rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)
      7 rules

D:\AnaConda\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\frequent_patterns\association_rules.py in association_rules(df, metric, min_threshold, support_only)
    127     values = df['support'].values
    128     frozenset_vect = np.vectorize(lambda x: frozenset(x))
--> 129     frequent_items_dict = dict(zip(frozenset_vect(keys), values))
    130 
    131     # prepare buckets to collect frequent rules

D:\AnaConda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1970             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   1971 
-> 1972         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   1973 
   1974     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

D:\AnaConda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2040             res = func()
   2041         else:
-> 2042             ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   2043 
   2044             # Convert args to object arrays first

D:\AnaConda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   1996             args = [asarray(arg) for arg in args]
   1997             if builtins.any(arg.size == 0 for arg in args):
-> 1998                 raise ValueError('cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs '
   1999                                  'unless `otypes` is set')
   2000 

ValueError: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set
```

This is what I have for dtypes in Pandas, any help would be appreciated.

```
col1    int64
col2    int64
col3    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Well, in this case, the result at the frequent_itemset were null at min_support=0.50. Altering to a lower value allows for results for the association rules to be applied to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Workaround:***

```
def encode_units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1

yourdataset_sets = yourdataset.applymap(encode_units)

frequent_itemsets = apriori(yourdataset_sets, min_support=0.001, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)
```

**Credit:**  [saeedesmaili](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend/issues/496)

Answer (score 3):

```
    128     frozenset_vect = np.vectorize(lambda x: frozenset(x))
--> 129     frequent_items_dict = dict(zip(frozenset_vect(keys), values))
```

Here `np.vectorize` wraps the `frozenset(x)` function in code that can take an array or list (`keys`), and pass each element for evaluation.  It a kind of `numpy` iteration (convenient, but not fast).  But to determine what kind (`dtype`) of array it returns it performs a test run with the first element of `keys`. An alternative to doing this test run is to use the `otypes` parameter.

Anyways, in this particular run, `keys` is evidently empty, a 0 size array or list. It could return an equivalent shape result array, but it still has to set a `dtype`.  Hence the error.

Evidently the code writer never anticipated the case where `keys` was empty.  So you need to tackle the question of why is it empty?

We need to look at the `association_rules` code see how `keys` is set.  Its use in line 129 suggests that it has the same number of elements as `values`, which is derived from the `df` with:

```
values = df['support'].values
```

If `keys` has 0 elements, then `values` does as well, and `df` has 0 'rows'.

What the size of `frequent_itemsets`?

I add a `mlxtend` tag because the error arises during the use of its code.  You/we need to examine that code or its documentation to determine why this dataframe is empty.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj, this issue is now raised on the developer's GITHUB: [rasbt](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend/issues/496). I hope your proposed solution helps solve the issue.

Comment: downgrading pandas  1.1.0 to 1.0.1 solved the issue for me (numpy version is 1.19.1)